# msp430g2253,Register manipulation

Tags: memory, cpu-registers, bare-metal

I'm working for the first time on msp430g2253 and I was reading the headers files to understand the programming aspect of registers and one thing that I didn't understand which is the register configuration.

For example I want to configure the clock module and this assignment: DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ; (DCOCTL is a register) (CALDCO_1MHZ is a value): how this direct address access works? This confuses me because I worked with stm32 and for register manipulation I needed it use to use pointers which was more understandable for address manipulation.

I really don't understand how this address manipulation is related to memory mapped. thank you